# Parsing a shell command output into two variables by line

Tags: shell, parsing, sh, ksh, ifs

I'm writing a script that outputs a bar graph of the sizes of the files/directories in a directory. I'm currently getting the required data with the line

`array=($(du -sc * | sort -hr))`

which results in every other line of `array` being a size and every other line a filename corresponding to it. However, if any of the filenames contain spaces, this naive approach doesn't work because the output is split at every space.

Basically what I want to do is parse the output line by line so that from each line I first get the characters up to the first space (the size), and then the rest of the line (the filename, which may or may not contain spaces). I thought about alternating the IFS between a space and a newline, but couldn't think of how exactly I would do that.

I'd prefer the solution to be portable between different shells, or at least to work in ksh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to read line by line is a `while read` loop, and `read` allows reading multiple fields:

```
names=() sizes=()

while read -r size name
do
    echo "The file '$name' has size $size"
    names+=("$name")
    sizes+=("$size")
done < <(du -sc ./* | sort -hr)
```

The `./*` prevents problems with files starting with dashes (for `du`) and leading spaces (for `read`).

Comment: One more question, how would I add those names and sizes into arrays so that I can loop over them? `names+="$name"` seems to do nothing.

Comment: Obviously this already loops over the items, but I modified it to append to arrays too.

Comment: This works in bash but gives an error in ksh and mksh. I'll just try to do without the arrays I guess.

Comment: @ltpour Works fine in my ksh 93u+. Which version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, it does work in ksh, it was another line in my code that gave the error. It does not work in mksh though, which is the shell I personally use. (The line with the < < syntax is the one that gives the error.) I'll try to work around it without using the arrays.